# Update all user's outlook with new Meeting Workspace default URL

Tags: 2010, url, outlook, meeting-workspace

Our organization would like to add a 'default url' to all client's outlook 2010 for meeting workspace.  Currently, they need to know the URL when creating a new meeting workspace, and I would like this to be automatically filled in.
Is there a group policy, registry entry, or Exchange Server setting I can use to update all users in our organization with this default URL?